# What type of memory is pointer pointing to in c?

Tags: pointers, ansi-c

I am trying to understand pointers more deeply and I got to a situation where I don't know to what type of memory do the pointers point to. Do I understand it correctly that if the pointers point to dynamically allocated variables through `malloc()` or `calloc()` then the pointer points to **RAM** and if there are static arrays or some variables then the pointer points to the memory (**SSD/HDD**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Conceptually, all memory is RAM, borrowed from the OS which manages it (if there is an OS). The difference between statics/globals and dynamic memory is that statics/globals are designed to never be returned to the OS until the program exits/dies whereas dynamically allocated memory (`malloc`/`calloc`/`mmap`) is conceptually returnable, which is what `free`/`munmap` is for.

(Note that when you `free` `malloc`'d/`calloc`'d memory, you only return in to your C standard library, which returns it to the OS at its own discretion (if it does at all).)

Comment: Thanks it helpt a lot